# size (in KB) of variable in php

Tags: php

is it possible to calculate / estimate the size (in KB) of a variable (string, array but mostly array). What happen is that we store some data inside memcache, and we would like to know how much memory space that data would take inside memcache.

Answer (score 11):

I believe PHP's memcache implementation uses [serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) when storing in memcached. You can simply `serialize` the output and check it's size:

```
<?php
$data = array('foo' => 'bar');
$serialized_data = serialize($data);
$size = strlen($serialized_data);
# `strlen` returns number of chars in a string. Each char is 1 byte.
# So to get size in bits, multiply `strlen` results by 8. Divide by
# 1024 for KB or KiB. Divide by 1000 for kB.
print($size * 8 / 1000);
?>
```

Comment: Remember if you're using Memcache there's a flag (MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED) that indicates if the data will be compressed. So, if the data is compressed then the size may change.

Comment: Right, there's also `HAVE_JSON` which would use json serialization instead of php serialization. Unfortunately I don't know what compression is used (but I assume gzip) so that only make it harder to guess the resulting size.

Comment: "Use MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED to store the item compressed (uses zlib)" It's ok though, it would be too much certainty ;)

Comment: Ah, well I leave checking for HAVE_JSON and MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED with "item values longer than a certain threshold (currently 100 bytes)" as an exercise for the OP.

Comment: 1024 bytes  = 1 KB so it should be  $size / 1024. Or I'm missing something ?

Comment: It depends. http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13815/files-size-units-kib-vs-kb-vs-kb

Comment: Is it correct? Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11367034/4440675
Yours approach will give a different result.

Comment: Different than what? Data memory usage in PHP is different that data memory usage in memcached.