# How to get the size of the content of a variable in PHP

Tags: php

If I have the following variable in PHP:

```
$Message='Hello, this is just test message';
```

How can I get the size of its content in bytes? For instance, to print something like:

```
<p>Message size is 20KB</p>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$start_memory = memory_get_usage();
$foo = "Some variable";
echo memory_get_usage() - $start_memory;
```

This is good if you are working with any type of var.

Comment: This is a bit off. `memory_get_usage() returns the amount of memory, in bytes, that's currently being allocated to your PHP script. ` Your script allocated memory to set the variable `$foo` as well as memory to set the variable `$foo` to a string and append a value. The result is higher than the actual bit/byte count of the string.

Comment: then why does it always return 272 both when I use `"Some variable"` as string or `"Some variable Some variable Some variable"` (many times)? Even if I assign empty string it still shows 272. It seems that this method is not accurate

Comment: Incorrect, does not take into account storage overheads as it calls generic PHP script memory usage.

Comment: This is highly inaccurate if used in an actual program or even if the variable is already in use.

Comment: Why is this checked, this does not answer the question.

Comment: If you are optimizing the php for runtime, this method is highly recommended since it gives an actual usage with all the overhead of the compiler/execution engine. Upvoted.!!

Comment: this is not the correct answer, but this is the answer I was looking for - so this gets an upvote ;)

Answer (score 62):

[`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) returns the number of bytes in the string, not the character length. View the PHP Manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php).

Look closely at:

> **Note:**
>
> strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string.

If you take the result and multiple by 8, you can get bits.

Here is a function which can easily do the math for you.

```
function strbits($string){
    return (strlen($string)*8);
}
```

**Note**, if you use, `memory_get_usage()`, you will have the wrong value returned. Memory get usage is the amount of memory allocated by the PHP script. This means, within its parser, it is allocating memory for the string and the value of the string. As a result, the value of this before and after setting a var, would be higher than expected.

Example, the string: `Hello, this is just test message`, produces the following values:

```
Memory (non-real): 344 bytes
Strlen: 32 Bytes
Strlen * 8bits: 256 bits
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$mem1 = memory_get_usage();
$a = 'Hello, this is just test message';

echo "Memory (non-real): ". (memory_get_usage() - $mem1)."\n";
echo "Strlen: ". strlen($a)."\n";
echo "Strlen * 8bits: ". (strlen($a) * 8)."\n";
```

Comment: What is faster if I do not need an accurate result, `strlen` or `memory_get_usage`?

Comment: But how to get size of an arrays or objects?

Comment: You can use the `memory_get_usage()` solution if you are dealing with complex objects and not strings. One might suggest that you can `serialize()` your object, but that's a crappy approach imo since serialization uses arbitrary characters for field delineation and type handling and takes away the memory footprint required by certain types (strings != int != float != etc).

Answer (score 8):

A character is one byte, so just check the string length.  Divide by 1024 if you need it in KB (be prepared for a decimal).

```
<?php echo "Message size is ".strlen($Message)."B"; ?>
```

Comment: only one who said divide by 1024 for getting KB, i believe everyone know this but no one mention it , up voted

Comment: yup, the string given is about .03KB

Answer (score 5):

**[`strlen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)** returns the number of bytes in a string.

Edit: (from the PHP Manual page)

> **Note:
>
>   strlen()** returns the number of bytes rather than the number of
>   characters in a string.
>   
>   **Note:
>
>   strlen()** returns NULL when executed on arrays, and an E_WARNING
>   level error is emitted.

Comment: Would the length be equal to the size in bytes?
a character is 8 bits or not?

Comment: A character is 1 byte (8 bits).

Comment: @ametren: Not always, multibyte strings (Unicode encoded) and may contain characters with more than 1 byte.

Comment: @ametren: Counts the bytes, not the nubmer of characters, which is exactly what OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/mrsuh/php-var-sizeof
It provides function `var_sizeof()` for getting size of any PHP variable in bytes.
It must be more accurate tool to calculate total size of PHP variable than `memory_get_usage()`.

```php
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$message='Hello, this is just test message';

printf("\$message size is %d bytes\n", var_sizeof($message));
```

```sh
$message size is 48 bytes
```

Comment: Currently this throws ```Warning: Uncaught RuntimeException: Unsupported machine type in vendor/mrsuh/php-var-sizeof/src/VarInfo.php:16``` on an M1. (```"mrsuh/php-var-sizeof": "^1.2"```)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the string length function:

```
strlen($Message)
```

You should also check the php manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php